# docker for windowsでhello-worldが無反応

Tags: windows, docker

Dockerを勉強してみようと思い、
[Get started with Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)
を参考にDockerをインストールしました。

```
docker version
docker info
```

まではコマンドが実行でき、Version情報等が取得できました。
しかし、

```
docker run hello-world
```

を実行したところ、応答がなく、何も進まない状態です。
エラーが出るでもなく、何も起きないので困りました。
考えられる原因を教えてください。

環境は

- OS：Windows10 Pro バージョン1703
- Docker Version：17.06.0-ce

です。Hyper-Vは有効にしています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `docker` コマンドを実行した後、ログに何か出力されていませんでしょうか？ 私は試したことが無いのですが、Windows だと `Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Docker -After (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) | Sort-Object Time` でログが見れるようです。 （[参考](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/troubleshooting#finding-logs)）

Comment: ご紹介いただいたページ上部にあるテストスクリプトを実行したところ、動作するようになりました。…何故治ったのかいまいちはっきりとしませんが、ひとまずは使えるようになったので解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: お疲れ様です。もしよろしければ、スクリプトを実行したときに出てきたメッセージなどを[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)として投稿してくださいませんか？　後からこの質問を見に来た方に役立つと思いますし、私もどのような状況だったのか知りたいです。

Comment: スクリプトの実行結果追加しました。ちなみに、docker runが動作しなかった時のログを見てみたところ、`Failed to connect to the database open \\.\pipe\dockerDataBase: The system cannot find the file specified. ` というエラーが大量に挙がっていました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft のトラブルシューティング](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/troubleshooting)に載っている以下のコマンドを実行すると直りました。

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://aka.ms/Debug-ContainerHost.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression
```

ユーザ名は伏字にしていますが、スクリプトの実行結果を載せておきます。

```
PS C:\Users\*****> Invoke-WebRequest https://aka.ms/Debug-ContainerHost.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression
Checking for common problems
Describing Windows Version and Prerequisites
 [+] Is Windows 10 Anniversary Update or Windows Server 2016 675ms
 [+] Has KB3192366, KB3194496, or later installed if running Windows build 14393 139ms
 [+] Is not a build with blocking issues 27ms
 [-] Has 'Containers' feature installed 40.68s
   COMException: 要求された操作には管理者特権が必要です。
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 23
   Invoke-Test、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 253
   ItImpl、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 203
   It、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 117
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 21
   Describe、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Describe.ps1: 行 100
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 5
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 1
Describing Docker is installed
 [+] A Docker service is installed - 'Docker' or 'com.Docker.Service'  74ms
 [+] Service is running 28ms
 [+] Docker.exe is in path 2.11s
 [+] Docker is registered in the EventLog service 90ms
Describing User has permissions to use Docker daemon
 [+] docker.exe should not return access denied 47ms
Describing Windows container settings are correct
 [+] Do not have DisableVSmbOplock set to 1 31ms
 [+] Do not have zz values set 57ms
 [+] Do not have FDVDenyWriteAccess set to 1 31ms
Describing The right container base images are installed
 [-] At least one of 'microsoft/windowsservercore' or 'microsoft/nanoserver' should be installed 103ms
   ValidationMetadataException: 引数が null または空です。null または空でない引数を指定して、コマンドを再度実行してくだ
さい。
   ParameterBindingValidationException: パラメーター 'Property の引数を確認できません。引数が null または空です。null ま
たは空でない引数を指定して、コマンドを再度実行してください。
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 115
   Invoke-Test、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 253
   ItImpl、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 203
   It、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 117
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 112
   Describe、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Describe.ps1: 行 100
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 100
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 1
Describing Container network is created
 [+] At least one local container network is available 1.09s
 [-] At least one NAT, Transparent, or L2Bridge Network exists 88ms
   Expected {0} to be greater than {0}
   206:       $totalnets | Should BeGreaterThan 0
   Should<End>、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Assertions\Should.ps1: 行 92
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 206
   Invoke-Test、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 253
   ItImpl、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 203
   It、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 117
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 189
   Describe、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Describe.ps1: 行 100
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 119
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 1
 [-] NAT Network's vSwitch is internal 60ms
   Expected: {Internal}
   But was:  {}
   211:       $switchType | Should Be "Internal"
   Should<End>、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Assertions\Should.ps1: 行 92
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 211
   Invoke-Test、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 253
   ItImpl、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 203
   It、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 117
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 210
   Describe、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Describe.ps1: 行 100
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 119
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 1
 [+] A Windows NAT is configured if a Docker NAT network exists 423ms
 [-] Specified Network Gateway IP for NAT network is assigned to Host vNIC 38ms
   Expected: value to not be empty
   225:       $natGatewayIP | Should Not BeNullOrEmpty
   Should<End>、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Assertions\Should.ps1: 行 92
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 225
   Invoke-Test、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 253
   ItImpl、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 203
   It、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 117
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 224
   Describe、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Describe.ps1: 行 100
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 119
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 1
 [-] NAT Network's internal prefix does not overlap with external IP' 40ms
   Expected {0} to be greater than {0}
   252:         $hostips.Count | Should BeGreaterThan 0
   Should<End>、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Assertions\Should.ps1: 行 92
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 252
   Invoke-Test、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 253
   ItImpl、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 203
   It、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\It.ps1: 行 117
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 239
   Describe、C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Describe.ps1: 行 100
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 119
   <ScriptBlock>、<ファイルなし>: 行 1
Showing output from: docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
runc version: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.31-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.934GiB
Name: moby
ID: G2Q2:ZHS2:EZFE:VLC7:COUL:H3KD:JMFX:J2SL:6QKN:SCNW:4F6K:S6UG
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 16
 Goroutines: 25
 System Time: 2017-07-05T13:54:02.1659336Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false


Showing output from: docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:51:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

Showing output from: docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
0ea3950a9c16        bridge              bridge              local
e36397da09fd        host                host                local
15650113c9a6        none                null                local

Getting Warnings & errors in the Windows event logs from the last 24 hours
Logs saved to C:\Users\*****\logs_20170705-225406.csv


Getting Docker for Windows daemon logs from the last execution
    Note: More logs are available at C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Docker. Only showing the latest.
PS C:\Users\****> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:51:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```